# Nuget package manager not working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

Nuget package manager suddenly stopped working in my VS 2015 environment.
It shows me the following error:

> [nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.   An error occurred while sending
>   the request.   The server committed a protocol violation.
>   Section=ResponseStatusLine

Any ideas how to get rid and make Nuget working in my box?

Comment: Try to run VS as administrator. Looks like VS haven't access to internet.

Comment: I have the same issue.  Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: Same problem here, appeared spontaneously, it seems a network problem, but no solution so far.

Comment: In case it happens again, install Fiddler if you can, to see what the HTTP response is for the request for index.json, and make sure it's valid JSON. If you can't install fiddler, you can just try opening the index.json file in a web browser on the same machine, running as the same user.